# How to efficiently overwrite parts of a string by index in .NET?

Tags: .net, string, stringbuilder

In my .NET program I allow a user to define "fields" which are values calculated by the business logic. These fields have a position and length, so that they can all be inserted into a single output string at a given index. I also allow a user to specify default content of this output string. If no field is defined to replace a given position, the default character is output instead

My question is, how can I do this efficiently? The StringBuilder class has an **Insert(int index, string value)** method, but this lengthens the output string each time rather than overwriting it. Am I going to have to set each char one at a time using the **StringBuilder[int index]** indexer, and is this inefficient? Since I am going to be doing this a lot of times I would like it to be as fast as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: " *Since I am going to be doing this a lot of times I would like it to be as fast as possible* ". Define 'a lot'? Thousands of times per button click? Then this is premature optimisation. A millions times an hour on a nightly batch job? Also premature optimisation (one milltion hits over an hour works out at approx 278 times per second). I'll be stunned if this string manipulation turns out to be a bottle neck.

Comment: True, but it is still nice to write efficient code if possible. I was just checking that I wasn't doing something horribly inefficient. As a .NET developer you are always hearing about how bad string manipulation can have performance penalties.

The core of this program is actually going to be used in several projects. The first involves file conversion. The output file contains values that are produced based on an input file. I believe each input file will likely contain hundreds if not thousands of records. But future applications that use this code might have heavier workloads.

Comment: You're probably better off then thinking in terms of appending fields to streams, rather than building a string and writing it. Using `System.IO.StringWriter` you can always get the output as a string if you need it for any reason.

Comment: I am actually using a StreamWriter to output the file. But I use the StringBuilder to build up individual sections that get passed to the StreamWriter.

Comment: I were quirious, and profiled Split vs StringBuilder solution, Split-Zip solution performs better :) here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/pKsaexWX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it one character at a time is likely your best bet. I say this because calling `Insert` and `Remove` on a `StringBuilder` results in characters being shifted right/left, just as the analogous methods would in any mutable indexed collection such as a `List<char>`.

That said, this is an excellent candidate for an extension method to make your life a bit easier.

```
public static StringBuilder ReplaceSubstring(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, int index, string replacement)
{
    if (index + replacement.Length > stringBuilder.Length)
    {
        // You could throw an exception here, or you could just
        // append to the end of the StringBuilder -- up to you.
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < replacement.Length; ++i)
    {
        stringBuilder[index + i] = replacement[i];
    }

    return stringBuilder;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder("My name is Dan.");
builder.ReplaceSubstring(11, "Bob");

Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

Output:

```
My name is Bob.
```

Comment: Grats for using ++i instead of i++ which drives me mad in for loops.

Answer (score 2):

The `StringBuilder` class lets you build a mutable string. Try using the `Remove` function before doing the `Insert`. Since its randomly accessible, it should be very quick. As long as the `StringBuilder` keeps the same capacity, it won't be taking time copying strings around in memory. If you know the string will become longer, try setting the capacity to be larger when you call `New StringBuilder()`

Comment: Using `Remove` and `Insert` *will* involve moving memory around.

Comment: Also, if fields is defined as (position, length) touple, you need to do some math, if inserted text is shorter or longer than text, it substitutes.

Comment: +1 I had not thought to use the Remove method in conjunction with the Insert method. It is at least an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long, as strings are immuteble, each manipulation with it, will cause GC load, even StringBuilder insert/remove calls.
I would cut source string by insertion points, and then "zip" it with data, that need to be inserted.
After that you can just concat strings inside list, to get resulting string.

Here is a sample code that do split/zip operaions.
It assumes, that Fields are defined as touple of (position, length, value).

```
public class Field
{
    public int pos { get; set; }
    public int len { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = "You'r order price [price] and qty [qty].";
        var fields = new List<Field>();
        fields.Add(new Field()
        {
            pos = 18, 
            len = 7, 
            value = "15.99$",
            tag = "price"
        });
        fields.Add(new Field()
        {
            pos = 37-3,
            len = 5,
            value = "7",
            tag = "qty"
        });
        Console.WriteLine(Zip(Split(source, fields), fields));
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceRegex(source, fields));

    }

    static IEnumerable<string> Split(string source, IEnumerable<Field> fields)
    {
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var field in fields.OrderBy(q => q.pos))
        {
            yield return source.Substring(index, field.pos - index);
            index = field.pos + field.len;
        }
        yield return source.Substring(index, source.Length - index);
    }
    static string Zip(IEnumerable<string> splitted, IEnumerable<Field> fields)
    {
        var items = splitted.Zip(fields, (l, r) => new string[] { l, r.value }).SelectMany(q => q).ToList();
        items.Add(splitted.Last());
        return string.Concat(items);
    }
    static string ReplaceRegex(string source, IEnumerable<Field> fields)
    {
        var fieldsDict = fields.ToDictionary(q => q.tag);
        var re = new Regex(@"\[(\w+)\]");
        return re.Replace(source, new MatchEvaluator((m) => fieldsDict[m.Groups[1].Value].value));
    }
}
```

BTW, would be better to replace special user markers, like [price], [qty] using regex?

Comment: StringBuilders, unlike normal strings, are not immutable.

Comment: But they operate on array of bytes inside, and insertion in the middel of the array, will cause memory reallocation.

Comment: +1 for an interesting solution. But it would be too much work to change my existing code to work like this, especially as I have a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `StringBuilder` class. However you can do it with a string but there can be side effects. Here are a couple blog posts that show how to manipulate strings and the possible side effects.

http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/are-strings-really-immutable-in-net/

http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/string-manipulation-in-net-epilogue-plus-new-theme/

Answer (score 0):

If your string is already pre formated for the length then the StringBuilder class has

```
public StringBuilder Replace(string oldValue, string newValue, int startIndex, int count)
```

just set your start index and count = 1 so you can replace that specific instance.

Another thing you could do is use String.Format(). Convert all your pre defined fields into indexes so you get a string like "This {0} is very {1}" and then just match up the parameters to the specific index and do a String.Format(myString, myParams);

-Raul

Answer (score 0):

If replacing substrings is going to be a big bottleneck, you may want to ditch the substrings thing altogether. Instead, break up your data into strings that can be independently modified. Something like the following:

```
class DataLine
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
    public string Field3;

    public string OutputDataLine()
    {
        return Field1 + Field2 + Field3;
    }
}
```

That's a simple static example, but I'm sure that could be made more generic so that if every user defines fields differently you could handle it. After breaking your data into fields, if you still need to modify individual characters in the fields at least you're not touching the whole set of data.

Now, this may push the bottle neck to the OutputDataLine function, depending on what you're doing with the data. But that can be handled separately if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As you fairly stated, StringBuilder has Insert method but no Overwrite method.

So i have created the Overwrite extension method, see below, for my projects.

Note that it will cut the value if the StringBuilder has not enough room for it. You can easily modify it's logic, however.

```
    public static void Overwrite( this StringBuilder sb, int index, string value )
    {
        int len = Math.Min( value.Length, sb.Length - index );
        sb.Remove( index, len );
        sb.Insert( index, value.Substring( 0, len ) );
    }
```